# get specific object by attribute called id or name from list object c++

Tags: c++

I want to get/identify the object who has the Id `"C003"`, for example, to print all data of that object.

I receive the id typed with `cin` and store in a `string` variable.

I've been reading many webpages and YouTube tutorials that use function `find()` or `find_if()`, but those examples use only numbers, so the third parameter is just a number, like 2.

In my case, I have a list with objects, and my conditional is this:

```cpp
if(iterador->getName() == citysearch.getName()){
    cout<<"Name: ";
    cout<< iterador->getId()<<endl;
    cout<<"Id: ";
    cout<< iterador->getName()<<endl;
    cout<<"------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    //break;
}
```

I type in the id, but it does not show anything. There is no error to show, or to search for in Google.

So, please help...  SOS.

City.h:

```cpp
class City{
public:
    City();
    City(string id, string name);
    string getId();
    void setId(string id);
    string getName();
    void setName(string name);

private:
    string id;
    string name;
};
```

City.cpp:

```cpp
//constructors
City::City() {
}

City::City(string newId,string newName) {
    id=newId;
    name=newName;
}

//functions to get and set data
string City::getId(){
    return id;
};

void City::setId(string newId){
    nombre=name;
};

string City::getName(){
    return name;
};

void City::setName(string newName){
    name=newname;
};
```

main function:

```cpp
int main () {

    City c1("C001","Barcelona");
    City c2("C002","New York");
    City c3("C003","San Andres");

    list<City> listcity;
    listcity.push_back(c1);
    listcity.push_back(c2);
    listcity.push_back(c3);

    string namecity;
    cin>>namecity;

    City citysearch;
    citysearch.setName(namecity);

    list<City>::iterator iterador=listcity.begin();
    list<City>::iterator iteradorfinal=listcity.end();

    while(iterador != iteradorfinal){

        if(iterador->getName() == citysearch.getName()){
            cout<<"Name: ";
            cout<< iterador->getId()<<endl;
            cout<<"Id: ";
            cout<< iterador->getName()<<endl;
            cout<<"------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;

            //break;
            iterador++;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where in the code you are assigning value to citysearch.setName?

Comment: This Code cannot run because `City` has 2 methods named `setId`. It is in your best interests to provide compliable code when you are hunting for a runtime error. See [mre] for advice on how to construct a good code example. As an added bonus MRE is a fabulous debugging tool. Odds ae good you'll get part way into the making and find the bug yourself.

Comment: IMHO, you should not use function calls inside an `if` statement.  Set up temporaries and assign them before the `if` statement, then compare the temporaries.  This allows you to place a breakpoint at the `if` statement and see what the values are before comparing.  Values returned from a function call are more difficult to view or watch when using a debugger.

Comment: You have `list<Robot>`, but you push variables of `City`.  How is the type `Robot` related to type `City`?

Comment: You should assign a constant iterator to `listcity.end()`.  This will prevent the compiler from calling the `listcity.end()` for every iteration.  The list doesn't change, so the end value will be constant; no need to call it every iteration. (Although some compilers may apply this optimization at higher optimization levels, IMHO, you always try to help out the compiler.)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews yep, that robot is my error writing

Comment: The code you posted does not compile.  How did you get it to run?  For example, in `setId()`, you have `nombre=name;`.  There is no `nombre` member nor is it the parameter.

Comment: BTW, because some city names, like `New York` contain spaces, when you use `std::cin >> namecity`, the input will stop at the first space character.  Try using `std::getline`.

Comment: Both `City::getId()` and `City::getName()` return the same member, `id`.

Comment: Seriously, the errors I'm finding can be found by using a debugger.  Please use a debugger, then edit your post with the text of your debugging results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've been reading many webpages and YouTube tutorials that use function `find()` or `find_if()`, but those examples use only numbers, so the third parameter is just a number, like 2.

The 3rd parameter of `std::find()`, and the parameter of the `std::find_if()` predicate, can take any type that is compatible with the type referred to by the iterator range that is being searched.

For instance, to use `std::find()` with your `City` class, you need to define an `operator==()` for it, such as to compare `name`s.  To use `std::find_if()`, you need a lambda/functor that takes a `City` as a parameter and returns a `bool` indicating whether that `City` object matches your criteria.

For example, try this:

City.h:

```
#ifndef City_H
#define City_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class City{
public:
    City();
    City(const std::string &newId, const std::string &newName);
    std::string getId() const;
    void setId(const std::string &newId);
    std::string getName() const;
    void setName(const std::string &newName);

    bool operator==(const City &city) const;

private:
    std::string id;
    std::string name;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const City &city);

#endif
```

City.cpp:

```cpp
#include "City.h"

//constructors
City::City() {
}

City::City(const std::string &newId, const std::string &newName) :
    id(newId), name(newName)
{
}

//functions to get and set data
std::string City::getId() const {
    return id;
}

void City::setId(const std::string &newId) {
    id = newId;
}

std::string City::getName() const {
    return name;
};

void City::setName(const std::string &newName){
    name = newName;
}

bool City::operator==(const City &city) const {
    return name == city.getName();
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const City &city) {
    out << "Id: " << city.getId() << "\n";
    out << "Name: " << city.getName() << "\n";
    out << "------------------------------------------------------------\n";
    return out;
}
```

main function:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include "City.h"

int main () {

    City c1("C001", "Barcelona");
    City c2("C002", "New York");
    City c3("C003", "San Andres");

    std::list<City> listcity;
    listcity.push_back(c1);
    listcity.push_back(c2);
    listcity.push_back(c3);

    std::string namecity;
    std::getline(std::cin, namecity);

    City citysearch;
    citysearch.setName(namecity);

    // using std::find()
    auto iterador = std::find(listcity.begin(), listcity.end(), citysearch);
    if (iterador != listcity.end()) {
        std::cout << *iterador;
    }

    // using std::find_if()
    iterador = std::find_if(listcity.begin(), listcity.end()
        [&](const City &city){ return city.getName() == namecity; }
    );
    if (iterador != listcity.end()) {
        std::cout << *iterador;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ITS PERFECT!!! Thank you so much :'3 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

One problem is: you only increment the iterator if the name matches.  If the name does not match, the iterator stays the same, and it gets into an infinite loop.

Try moving the iterator outside the `if` statement:

```
while(iterador != listcity.end()){

    if(iterador->getName() == citysearch.getName()){
        cout<<"Name: ";
        cout<< iterador->getId()<<endl;
        cout<<"Id: ";
        cout<< iterador->getName()<<endl;
        cout<<"------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
        //break;
    }
    iterador++;
}
```

Another issue is that `getName` returns the `id` but it's likely that you wanted to return the `name` instead.

Also, not related, but the `setId` function is setting the name to itself isnstead of setting the `id`.

Comment: thats one error, ty but i moved it and nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version of your posted code, which runs correctly.
Changes were made for compilation.
See my comments above.

```
//file City.h
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::list;
using std::cin;

class City{
public:
City();
City(string id, string name);
string getId();
void setId(string id);
string getName();
void setName(string name);


private:
   string id;
   string name;
};

//file City.cpp

    //constructors
    City::City() {
    }
    City::City(string newId,string newName)
    {
        id=newId;
        name=newName;
    }
        //functions to get and set data
        string City::getId(){
            return id;
        };
        void City::setId(string newId){
            id = newId;
        };
        string City::getName(){
            return name;
        };
        void City::setName(string newName){
            name=newName;
        };
    ///
        
//main function
int main () {

City c1("C001","Barcelona");
City c2("C002","New York");
City c3("C003","San Andres");

list<City> listcity;
listcity.push_back(c1);
listcity.push_back(c2);
listcity.push_back(c3);


string namecity;
std::cout << "Enter city name: ";
std::getline(std::cin, namecity);

City citysearch;
citysearch.setName(namecity);

list<City>::iterator iterador=listcity.begin();

while(iterador != listcity.end())
{
    const std::string  list_name(iterador->getName());
    const std::string   search_name(citysearch.getName());
    std::cout << "City name from list: " << list_name << "\n";
    std::cout << "City name to search: " << search_name << "\n\n";
    if(list_name == search_name){
        cout<<"Name: ";
        cout<< iterador->getId()<<endl;
        cout<<"Id: ";
        cout<< iterador->getName()<<endl;
        cout<<"------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;

        break;
    }
    iterador++;
    
}

return 0;
}
```

As you can see above, I added code to print the city name from the list and the city name to search for.

### Use Case: City not found

```
$ ./city.exe
Enter city name: Los Angeles
City name from list: Barcelona
City name to search: Los Angeles

City name from list: New York
City name to search: Los Angeles

City name from list: San Andres
City name to search: Los Angeles
```

### Use case: City Found

```
$ ./city.exe
Enter city name: New York
City name from list: Barcelona
City name to search: New York

City name from list: New York
City name to search: New York

Name: C002
Id: New York
------------------------------------------------------------
```

I highly recommend:

1. Using a debugger.  Step through your code one statement at a time.
2. When in doubt, print the variables before your comparisons.